# Access subsite from parent site using sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api, boomi, mule-connector

I am trying to get all the folders in the subsite, the below URL returns all the folders inside my subsite when I use the subsite in the URI

I am using Mulesoft on new object oob sharepoint connector.

```
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Test2/projects/mysubsite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('documents')/Folders
```

but I need to access it via a relative URL that does not return any folders, can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong here.

Test2 is my parent site, projects is a web part and mysubsite is a site under which we have the folder

```
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Test2/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('sites/Test2/projects/mysubsite/documents')/Folders
```

Comment: What MuleSoft product are you using to access the URL? Please share the configurations.

Comment: I am using SharePoint connector, but I am trying to find the correct url, so I can use http connector

Comment: Then the question has no Mule nor MuleSoft component. It is purely about Sharepoint. Not sure why the boomi tag.

Comment: The tag is because normally these operations are performed from Mule and Boomi, so people with Integration experience would be able to answer this